# Do HSAs have income limits for deducting contributions?

Tags: united-states, hsa, hdhp

Traditional IRAs have [income limits for claiming contributions as deductions](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/2018-ira-contribution-and-deduction-limits-effect-of-modified-agi-on-deductible-contributions-if-you-are-covered-by-a-retirement-plan-at-work). **Do HSAs also have income limits for claiming contributions as deductions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not read of any income limits for making or claiming contributions to an HSA.

[This site](https://thecollegeinvestor.com/20912/hsa-contribution-income-limits/) mentions that there are no income limits for making contributions to HSA.

If you have an employer-sponsored plan, contributions are generally deducted as a pre-tax contribution so this isn't an issue.

If you opened/hold an HSA outside of an employer (like self-employed folks), you would contribute like you would with a Traditional IRA.

The instructions for IRS Form 8889 (where you report your HSA contributions and distributions) will tell you the limits of what you're allowed to contribute but doesn't mention any income limits either.

After you go through Form 8889, it'll tell you where to put your deduction: Schedule 1 (Form 1040), line 25, or Form 1040NR, line 25.

From all this, I would say there are no income limits for claiming contributions as deductions.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned employer sponsored plans adding my contributions via payroll deduction. That completely slipped my mind, which means I can't mark those as contributions on [Form 8889](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8889.pdf), Line 2.